# How do i know what CRUD operations are performing by my java application?

Tags: java

I have an application which was closed to enhance and for audit purpose i want to know what are the DB operations performing by an java application. I dont want to enhance my application to provide those details but is there a way to know? any external tool that monitor db calls?

Comment: Maybe (MAYBE, haven checked or read) those stuff like JConsole that hooks into the JVM for surveillance is able to. This product http://www.appdynamics.com/solutions/appdynamics-java-monitoring/free-java-monitoring-tools for example claims its able to see SQL stuff in the Pro-Version...

Answer (score 0):

Enable **query log** for the application. Along with that, you can even enable **slow query log** for the application. Please note, enabling query log will impact the performance of the application.

Also, the query log will not print the queries which are fired inside stored Procedures. (i.e. internla queries of Stored Procedure). It will show the invocation of stored procedure for sure.